# Linq - where inside include

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I know that this won't work as written, but I'm struggling to see the right answer, and this non-functional code hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

```
var defaults = _cilQueryContext.DefaultCharges
                    .Where(dc => dc.ChargingSchedule_RowId == cs.RowId);

List<DevelopmentType> devTypes = 
        defaults.Select(dc => dc.DevelopmentType)
                .Include(d => d.DefaultCharges)
                .Include(d => d.OverrideCharges.Where(oc => oc.ChargingSchedule_RowId == cs.RowId))
                .Include(d => d.OverrideCharges.Select(o => o.Zone))
                .ToList();
```

Essentially, I had presumed this required a join, but seeing as I'm trying to select a parent object containing two related types of children, I can't see what would go in the join's "select new" clause.

Comment: I really hope the `Include` could work this way, but looks like it can't, all the `included` data will be included without any pre-filtering :(

Comment: This is not supported by EntityFramework.

Comment: You need to use joins and then a projection instead of includes to achieve this result.

Comment: Thanks guys - but as stated I know it won't work as written and requires a join. I just need some help with the correct syntax for the join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware `Include` does not support this type of sub-querying. Your best option is to use projection e.g.

```
List<DevelopmentType> devTypes = 
           defaults.Include(x => x.DefaultCharges)
                   .Include(x => x.OverrideCharges)
                   .Select(x => new {
                        DevType = x.DevelopmentType,
                        Zones = x.OverrideCharges.Where(oc => oc.ChargingSchedule_RowId == cs.RowId)
                                                 .Select(oc => oc.Zone).ToList()
                   })
                   .Select(x => x.DevType)
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: surely you mean return tmp and not return dev?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I've been noodling around with your syntax and whichever way I stack it, I seem to get one of two errors. If I try and use a "select" in a similar manner to that suggested, I get cannot cast IQueryable to ICollection type errors. If I use ToList() (to make it ICollection), or trying using Add() to add items to the ICollection then I'm told "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree". Sorry to continue to rely on your brain, but I'm struggling with this.

Comment: @MattThrower What @James posted will not work with EF (and other providers) since the select body is not an expression (and thus can't be parsed into SQL). If you put `ToList()` *before* the `Select` it should work, but that would bring back unnecessary `OverrideCharges` from the db. You can still rework this by selecting an anonymous type that holds both a `DevelopmentType` and a filtered `OverrideCharges` property, then combine them once that is in memory.

Comment: @MattThrower see update. I was trying to avoid creating a new instance, however, I wasn't aware this wouldn't work in EF. Looking at the query in more detail though giving you only want to return the DevelopmentType I am wondering why you need to do the Zone selection at all here?