# Linq error when I use First() and FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I try to use this query with linq:

```
myQuery= myQuery.Where(c => c.RelatedEntity
                             .FirstOrDefault()
                             .MyStringProperty
                             .Contains(myString));
```

But it says that it is not possible to use `First()`, that I have to considerate to use `FirstOrDefault()`. But if I use first or default I get other error, `System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException`.

What I want is to find other MainEntities which related entity in the string property contain the string of the parameter given by the user.

Thanks.

EDIT: I add more info.

The code of my repository is:

```
using(catalogoEntitiesSQLiteEF5 miDBContext = new catalogoEntitiesSQLiteEF5())
{
    IQueryable<Contenidos> miConsulta = miDBContext.Contenidos.Include(c=>c.Videos.Select(v=>v.GenerosVideos));

    if (paramVideos.Titulo != null)
    {
        miConsulta = miConsulta.Where(c => c.Videos.First().Titulo.Contains(paramVideos.Titulo));
    }
    return miConsulta.ToList<Contenidos>();
}
```

The POCO entities:

```
public partial class Contenidos
{
    public Contenidos()
    {
        this.Ficheros = new HashSet<Ficheros>();
        this.Videos = new HashSet<Videos>();
    }

    public long IDContenido { get; set; }
    public long IDTipoContenido { get; set; }
    public string Observaciones { get; set; }

    public virtual TiposContenidos TiposContenidos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ficheros> Ficheros { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Videos> Videos { get; set; }
}

public partial class GenerosVideos
{
    public GenerosVideos()
    {
        this.Videos = new HashSet<Videos>();
    }

    public long IDGenero { get; set; }
    public string GeneroVideo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Videos> Videos { get; set; }
}

public partial class Videos
{
    public Videos()
    {
        this.Series = new HashSet<Series>();
        this.GenerosVideos = new HashSet<GenerosVideos>();
    }

    public long IDVideo { get; set; }
    public long IDContenido { get; set; }
    public long IDTipoVideo { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string TituloOriginal { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Duracion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Año { get; set; }
    public bool Favorito { get; set; }
    public bool Pendiente { get; set; }

    public virtual Contenidos Contenidos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Series> Series { get; set; }
    public virtual TiposVideos TiposVideos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GenerosVideos> GenerosVideos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you're expecting people to help you please at least make the effort to spell method names copied from your the framework correctly!

Comment: is c.RelatedEntity can be null ?

Comment: In case of no match found, FirstOrDefault will return default(Type) which will be most likely null which could further lead to NullReferenceException, that may be the reason why you're getting System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException

Comment: Model above it not working for me. ID fields are not correcly mapped. When I switched own object IDs to "ID" and referenced object IDs to ClassNameID (example: instead of IDContenido I put ContenidoID in the Video class) it worked fine with the query you put originally. After such changes I run Migrations to build DB. I'm using EF 5.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should work:

```
myQuery = myQyuery.Where(c => c.RelatedEntity
    .Any(x => x.MyStringProperty.Contains(myString)));
```

Comment: the problem that is the related entity is a list, that by bussiniss logic only can have one element, but when I create the POCO entities from the database the navigation property is created as a list. So I need to select the first element.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía What is `myQuery`? An `IEnumerable` of some sort? Perhaps you should add the relevant model to your question.

Comment: I added more information, the code and POCO classes, I think that this clears more the quiestion.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
myQuery= myQuery.Where(c => c.RelatedEntity.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyStringProperty.Contains(myString));
```

Answer (score 1):

If your list doesn't contain any elements, `FirstOrDefault()` will return null which will cause `NullReferenceException`.
To avoid it use:

```
myQuery= myQuery.Where(c => c.RelatedEntity
                             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyStringProperty
                                                   .Contains(myString)) != null);
```

The other issue is your usage of `Include()`. As pointed out by [James](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770841/linq-where-inside-include) it doesn't support sub-querying. Try to change your:

```
IQueryable<Contenidos> miConsulta =
    miDBContext.Contenidos.Include(c=>c.Videos.Select(v=>v.GenerosVideos));
```

To something like:

```
IQueryable<Contenidos> miConsulta =
       miDBContext.Contenidos.Include(x => x.Videos)
               .Select(x => new {
                    GenerosVideos = x.Videos.Select(v=>v.GenerosVideos).ToList()
               });
```

Comment: This gives me a System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException exception.

Comment: I found [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770841/linq-where-inside-include) which may solve your problem, however i'm not positive if my code is correct. Hope it helps.